# Copying new data from one table to another

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server Agent job setup that pulls Extended Event XML data into a SQL Server table. There's another table that gets uploaded with the Extended Event data after the XML data is shredded from the first table, so that its readable in the second table.

The problem is that the 2nd table gets dropped and recreated each time so that I don't have duplicate rows for each event.  I would like to setup a 3rd table that pulls from the 2nd table, but will only get changes to the data in the 2nd table.

Example:

Step 1: Delete all data from XMLstaging table

Step 2: Import XML data into XMLstaging table using -

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[XMLStaging] (event_data) (

    SELECT event_data = CONVERT(XML, event_data)
    FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(N'C:\XE results - Logins\AuditLogins*.xel', null, null, null)
);
```

Step 3: Delete all data from AuditLogins table

Step 4: Shred XML data and import in readable format to AuditLogins table -

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[AuditLogins] (timeofevent, errormessage, user_nm , nt_username, dbname, client_hostname, client_app_name)
(
    SELECT 
        timeofevent    = event_data.value(N'(event/@timestamp)[1]', N'datetime'),
        errormessage = event_data.value(N'(event/data[(@name)[1] eq "message"]/value/text())[1]','varchar(255)'),
        user_nm  = event_data.value(N'(event/action[@name="username"]/value)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),
        nt_username   = event_data.value(N'(event/action[@name="username"]/value)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),
        dbname  = event_data.value(N'(event/action[@name="database_name"]/value)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),
        client_hostname = event_data.value(N'(event/action[@name="client_hostname"]/value)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),
        client_app_name  = event_data.value(N'(event/action[@name="client_app_name"]/value)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)')
    FROM 
        [dbo].[XMLStaging]
);
```

Step 5: Insert rows to the new table from the AuditLogins that weren't there before it was dropped and recreated.  The rows that were there before it was dropped and recreated should already be in the new table from the last time this job ran.

My goal is to eventually have an eventid primary key column on the new table and only one row for each event.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you dont have a PK on the tables then you will probably just need to insert with a left join where null

Comment: What do I join on if there's nothing unique in either table?

Comment: you could join on each of the columns, but that would prevent duplicates though